# Как правильно делать jar файл?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Написал несколько вспомогательных классов на Java под Eclipse. Сделал export их в jar файл и подсоединил к другому проекту (файл виден в JRE System Library). Возникла проблема что не могу импортировать эти классы к проекту, пока не пропишу их в Access rulles (cм. аттач). В тоже время когда использую другие jar файлы скачанные на просторах интернета (например jdbc.jar драйвер, или jxl.jar лля создания excel файла) то таких проблем нет. Как исправить ситуацию с моим jar файлом?[image: screen shot from eclipse]

Comment: Корень пакета у вас лежит в корне архива?

Comment: Да конечно. То есть войдя в jar файл сразу видна/доступна директория db.